# Need help identifying an unopened LEGO bag - lime green and black pieces

Tags: set-identification, vehicle

We found an unopened bag of lime green and black pieces. Son does not remember what or where it came from which is odd because he's always eager to assemble sets when he gets them. Looks like some sort of vehicle since there is a windshield, wheels and steering with pieces that are smooth on the outside.

[image: Lime green pieces with windshield, wheels and steering wheel]

[image: Lime green pieces with windshield, wheels and steering wheel]

[image: Lime green pieces with windshield, wheels and steering wheel]

Comment: I fixed the photo links - if I had done that first, it might have been easier to find, as I only went off the first photo.

Answer (score 4):

[76899-1](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=76899-1) Lamborghini Urus ST-X & Lamborghini Huracán Super Trofeo EVO

Based on

- Black Brick 1 x 10
- Lime Plate 1 x 6
- Lime Slope, Curved 8 x 2

[image: 76899-1]